# Quickest way to count a large amount of data in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have over 100k numbers - these will be anywhere from 0 to 2000

currently they are in a single column in excel, and what im trying to do is group them so excel for example counts 40 as being within range 0 - 99

is this possible - if so how?

so the data is

```
59
356
708
108
116
100
116
433
536
454
595
549
85
101
100
116
116
147
180
169
138
216
85
285
332
332
301
153
337
637
306
153
154
113
1681
1834
1599
1524
1614
1703
174
75
161
217
142
171
228
264
421
284
143
318
116
135
113
106
```

and what i want back is

```
0 - 99    10
100 - 199  23
```

etc

Comment: could you mock up what you are expecting for an output?  a simple countifs would do it: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=0",A:A,"<=99")`

Answer (score 1):

Place the upper and lower limits to you "buckets" in columns **B** and **C**.  Then in **D1** enter Scott's formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=" & B1,A:A,"<=" & C1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a built-in toolkit which includes the ability to create a [Histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) AKA "frequency distribution".

You'll need to enable the Analysis Toolpak in the Add-ins section of the Options menu. From there you create the "bins" of numbers for which you wish to find frequencies. The whole process is detailed by Microsoft [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214269)

[image]